# How to Fix Error That Prevents Filtering Results in a List

Tags: java, android

I'm having a hard time implementing record filtering functionality in my listing code using `RecyclerView` and `SearcView`.

my code lists all the books in the database, but one line of code is not correct as I don't know how to fix it.

I marked the lines saying `// requires your attention!` to help.

The question is? what do I go through in this constructor?

```
    recyclerAdapter = new BookAdapter();
```

This error in line is **error: constructor BookAdapter in class BookAdapter cannot be applied to given types; required: `List<Book>`,Context found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

- In `BookAdapter.java` the constructor is:

```
    List<Book> books;
    List<Book> books2;
    Context context;
    DB db;

    public BookAdapter(List<Book> books, Context context) {
        this.books = books;
        this.books2 = new ArrayList<>(books2);
        this.context = context;
        db = new DB(context);
    }
```

- Code

```
    public class ListBooks extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        BookAdapter recyclerAdapter; // requires your attention!
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_book);
            set.title("List books");
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerAdapter = new BookAdapter(); // requires your attention!
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter); // requires your attention!
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    
            DB db = new DB(this);
            List<Book> books = db.ReadBook();
            
            if (book.size() > 0){
                BookAdapter bookadapter = new BookAdapter(books,ListBooks.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(bookadapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No books in database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_book,menu);
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.s_book);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    recyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText); // requires your attention!
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the actual errors.

Comment: If the ctor requires parameters you should probably pass those parameters.

Comment: @DaveNewton ok, wait a moment!

Comment: @DaveNewton this done.

Comment: Same comment as my second comment.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you can create classes in Java and instantiate instances of them.

The constructor is there to tell you what a class needs to create an instance of itself.

You created this constructor:

```
public BookAdapter(List<Book> books, Context context) {
    this.books = books;
    this.books2 = new ArrayList<>(books2);
    this.context = context;
    db = new DB(context);
}
```

There are 2 problems here:

1. In the current state of the constructor, books2 doesn't have a value. So you are basically copying something that doesn't exist yet. I think you ment to call `this.books2 = new ArrayList<>(books);`, which creates a copy of the `ArrayList` books, instead of `this.books2 = new ArrayList<>(books2);`
2. In the constructor, you told Java that you need 2 things to create a BookAdapter: A `List<Book>` and a `Context`. When you now want to use this constructor, Java expects you to actually transfer those things. So call `recyclerAdapter = new BookAdapter(Arrays.asList(/*pass all your books here*/), this);`

The `AppCompatActivity` (ListBooks) you are creating the instance from extends `Context`, so it is a context. By using this, you can transfer the class you are currently in, in this case your `ListBooks.class`.